# Strlen of GET variable

Tags: php, get

I have a strange bug in my site:
I have a get variable in url `?getClass=9а`
For some reason when I output it's strlen it is on 1 symbol more than it actually is.
For example:
9a strlen - 3
10a strlen - 4
11a strlen - 4
The other strange thing is that when I try to substring using it's strlen:

```
$classNumber=substr($_GET['getClass'],0,strlen($_GET['getClass']-1));
$classLetter=substr($_GET['getClass'], strlen($_GET['getClass']-1));
```

The result is like this:
9a $classNumber=9 $classLetter=а that's ok 
10а $classNumer=1 $classLetter=0a that's wrong 
11a $classNumber=11 $classLetter=a that's ok again.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: @user4035 gave the correct answer, that was for some reason heavily downvoted: you're using **cyrillic** `a` (`U+0430`) which is encoded with two bytes (`\xd0\xb0`) in UTF-8. Therefore, `strlen`, which counts bytes and not characters, returns 3.

Comment: Yep the problem is in cirillic character I suppose, so no of answers works.

Comment: I've reposted their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This correct answer was originally posted by [user4035](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789186/user4035) but downvoted and deleted for some reason.

---

The reason of this behaviour is that you are using a cyrillic "а", and not a latin one. And it is considered as a unicode character, represented with 2 bytes. You need to use [mb_strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) function:

```
<?php
print strlen($_GET['getClass'])."<br>";
print mb_strlen($_GET['getClass'], 'utf8');
```

For input: "9а" it will print:

```
3
2
```

But if you use plain ASCII, the functions will give the same result:

getClass=99

```
2
2
```

Comment: Well, I'll mark your answer because actually problem was in cyrillic symbol but I used gerexp like this:/^(\d+)([А-Яа-я]+)$/

Answer (score 4):

You should substract the *-1* from the strlen result not from the string.

```
$classNumber=substr($_GET['getClass'],0,strlen($_GET['getClass'])-1);
$classLetter=substr($_GET['getClass'], strlen($_GET['getClass'])-1);
```